# Objects and Timers (For Loops)

Tags: java, loops, object, timer, invisible

This is a school project. I am trying to get a collision game working, where the goal is to evade the balls. I am currently working on, and having problems, in trying to have a ball added every 30 seconds or so. I have tried both for loops and timers to solve this part (In the code I have for loops). I have gotten the same results repeatedly: The ball is still there but invisible. If anyone knows how to fix this problem or a different method that might work, please help. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Formatter;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
public class  Man extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

private static final int BOX_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int BOX_HEIGHT = 480;
private float ballSpeedX3 = 7;
private float ballSpeedY3 = 7;
private double ball3Radius = 20;
private double ball3X = 320 ;
private double ball3Y = 120 ;
private float ballSpeedX4 = -10;
private float ballSpeedY4 = 10;
private double ball4Radius = 15;
private double ball4X = 600 ;
private double ball4Y = 300 ;
private float ballSpeedX = 0;
private float ballSpeedY = 0;
private double ballRadius = 20;
private double ballX = 120;
private double ballY = 140;
private float ballSpeed1X = 10;
private float ballSpeed1Y = -10;
private double ballRadius1 = 20;
private double ball1X = 320;
private double ball1Y = 340;
private float ballSpeed2X = -3;
private float ballSpeed2Y = -3;
private double ballRadius2 = 50;
private double ball2X = 50;
private double ball2Y = 400;

private static final int UPDATE_RATE = 30;

public Man() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT));
    Thread gameThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
while(true){             

              if ( Math.sqrt(    (Math.pow((ballX- ball1X), 2))    +    Math.pow((ballY-ball1Y), 2)) <= (ballRadius1 + ballRadius)) {
    System.exit(0);}
              if ( Math.sqrt(    (Math.pow((ball4X- ballX), 2))    +    Math.pow((ball4Y-ballY), 2)) <= (ball4Radius + ballRadius)) {
                    System.exit(0);}
              if ( Math.sqrt(    (Math.pow((ball2X- ballX), 2))    +    Math.pow((ball2Y-ballY), 2)) <= (ballRadius2 + ballRadius)) {
                System.exit(0);}        

                  ball4X += ballSpeedX4;
                  ball4Y += ballSpeedY4;
                  if (ball4X - ball4Radius < 0) {
                      ballSpeedX4 = -ballSpeedX4;
                      ball4X = ball4Radius;
                  } else if (ball4X + ball4Radius > BOX_WIDTH) {
                      ballSpeedX4 = -ballSpeedX4;
                      ball4X = BOX_WIDTH - ball4Radius;
                  }
                  if (ball4Y - ball4Radius < 0) {
                      ballSpeedY4 = -ballSpeedY4;
                      ball4Y = ball4Radius;
                  } else if (ball4Y + ball4Radius > BOX_HEIGHT) {
                      ballSpeedY4 = -ballSpeedY4;
                      ball4Y = BOX_HEIGHT - ball4Radius;
                  }

              if ( Math.sqrt(    (Math.pow((ball3X- ballX), 2))    +    Math.pow((ball3Y-ballY), 2)) <= (ball3Radius + ballRadius)) {
                System.exit(0);}


                ball3X += ballSpeedX3;
                ball3Y += ballSpeedY3;
                if (ball3X - ball3Radius < 0) {
                    ballSpeedX3 = -ballSpeedX3;
                    ball3X = ball3Radius;
                } else if (ball3X + ball3Radius > BOX_WIDTH) {
                    ballSpeedX3 = -ballSpeedX3;
                    ball3X = BOX_WIDTH - ball3Radius;
                }
                if (ball3Y - ball3Radius < 0) {
                    ballSpeedY3 = -ballSpeedY3;
                    ball3Y = ball3Radius;
                } else if (ball3Y + ball3Radius > BOX_HEIGHT) {
                    ballSpeedY3 = -ballSpeedY3;
                    ball3Y = BOX_HEIGHT - ball3Radius;
                }

                ballX += ballSpeedX;

                ballY += ballSpeedY;


                if (ballX - ballRadius < 0) {

                    ballX = ballRadius;
                } else if (ballX + ballRadius > BOX_WIDTH) {

                    ballX = BOX_WIDTH - ballRadius;
                }

                if (ballY - ballRadius < 0) {

                    ballY = ballRadius;
                } else if (ballY + ballRadius > BOX_HEIGHT) {

                    ballY = BOX_HEIGHT - ballRadius;
                }

                ball1X += ballSpeed1X;
                ball1Y += ballSpeed1Y;
                if (ball1X - ballRadius1 < 0) {
                    ballSpeed1X = -ballSpeed1X;
                    ball1X = ballRadius1;
                } else if (ball1X + ballRadius1 > BOX_WIDTH) {
                    ballSpeed1X = -ballSpeed1X;
                    ball1X = BOX_WIDTH - ballRadius1;
                }

                if (ball1Y - ballRadius1 < 0) {
                    ballSpeed1Y = -ballSpeed1Y;
                    ball1Y = ballRadius1;
                } else if (ball1Y + ballRadius1 > BOX_HEIGHT) {
                    ballSpeed1Y = -ballSpeed1Y;
                    ball1Y = BOX_HEIGHT - ballRadius1;
                }
                ball2X += ballSpeed2X;
                ball2Y += ballSpeed2Y;
                if (ball2X - ballRadius2 < 0) {
                    ballSpeed2X = -ballSpeed2X;
                    ball2X = ballRadius2;
                } else if (ball2X + ballRadius2 > BOX_WIDTH) {
                    ballSpeed2X = -ballSpeed2X;
                    ball2X = BOX_WIDTH - ballRadius2;
                }

                if (ball2Y - ballRadius2 < 0) {
                    ballSpeed2Y = -ballSpeed2Y;
                    ball2Y = ballRadius2;
                } else if (ball2Y + ballRadius2 > BOX_HEIGHT) {
                    ballSpeed2Y = -ballSpeed2Y;
                    ball2Y = BOX_HEIGHT - ballRadius2;
                }

                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            }
        }  
    };
    gameThread.start();

}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval((int) (ballX - ballRadius), (int) (ballY - ballRadius),
               (int)(2 * ballRadius), (int)(2 * ballRadius));
  for(int i=100 ; i < 5 ; i++){   g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval((int) (ball1X - ballRadius1), (int) (ball1Y - ballRadius1),

            (int)(2 * ballRadius1), (int)(2 * ballRadius1));  } 
    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.fillOval((int) (ball2X - ballRadius2), (int) (ball2Y - ballRadius2),
               (int)(2 * ballRadius2), (int)(2 * ballRadius2));   

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval((int) (ball3X - ball3Radius), (int) (ball3Y - ball3Radius),
                           (int)(2 * ball3Radius), (int)(2 * ball3Radius));
    for(int i=100 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval((int) (ball4X - ball4Radius), (int) (ball4Y - ball4Radius),
                           (int)(2 * ball4Radius), (int)(2 * ball4Radius));}


}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
        ballSpeedX = 5;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) {
        ballSpeedX = -5;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
        ballSpeedY = -5;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ) {
        ballSpeedY = 5;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
         ballSpeedX = 0;
     }
     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) {
         ballSpeedX = 0;
     }
     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
         ballSpeedY = 0;
     }
     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ) {
         ballSpeedY = 0;

     }  
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Collision");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Man man = new Man();

            frame.setContentPane(man);
            frame.pack();
            frame.addKeyListener(man);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is kinda long for me to read. But seeing that you are creating a new thread and calling `Thread.sleep`, I have a rough idea of where you did wrong.

In your new thread's code, you are updating the position of the ball (which is shown on the UI) and other stuff, right? This should be the cause of your problem.

*You should not (and usually could not) update the UI in any thread, except the UI thread.*

To do this, you can use `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer`. IMO, the former is easier and more suitable to use.

Just create a new timer and call `start`:

```
// declare a timer variable in class level first!
timer = new Timer(1000 / UPDATE_RATE, new ActionListener() {
    // all your code in the while loop...
    // do not include the "while(true)" part
});
timer.start();
```

Comment: thanks i am just going to reorganize my work in classes first